# How to delete synced photos from iPhone without connecting to mac?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, photos, macos

I have synced a folder which contains some pictures to my iPhone. The synced photos are successfully copied to my iPhone. But I can not see any "delete" option in my iPhone to remove the synced photos.

The "Camera Roll" which has the pictures that I took via the iPhone's camera have an option "delete" in the bottom of the picture. But synced photos does not have that delete button.

Should I use iTunes/Mac to delete synced photos? Can't I delete the synced photos with a single touch?

Comment: I had same issue and i found solution on youtube, you have to make fake folder to delete synced photos from iPhone ... here how you do in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRlEO1kMUmI
Hope this will help

Comment: This video explains it all! Even though we need to use iTunes, it is much easier to do than the answer provided below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Synced Photos* deleting must be done through iTunes. To do so just:

1. In **iTunes** select the device icon in the *Devices List* on the left. Click the *Photos* tab in the resulting window.
2. Choose *Sync photos from*, being **iPhoto** or **Aperture** on a Mac and **Photoshop Album** or **Photoshop Elements** on a Windows PC.
3. Choose *Select Albums* and **deselect** the albums or collections you want to delete.
4. Click Apply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I add photos to my iPhone without using the "sync" process? If so, does those pictures can be deleted without iTunes?

Comment: The only ways that come to my mind are sending them through mail and safe them to your camera roll, or using some sort of cloud storage as dropbox. Either way, you'll be able to delete them without iTunes.

Comment: Really thanks.. So, I'm clear now. I can not delete MY files from MY iDevice. :)

Comment: I can understand that you are Confused. ;)

Comment: I have an old iPhone 5s 64GB which contains ~11GB of photos. I have the photos archived, but I don't have access to the machine from which they were synced originally. I have tried syncing with a different machine with a folder containing just one photo, and still the old photos remain in the phone. I cannot delete them directly from the phone. I have also tried using Image Capture, but it doesn't even show the photos in the list. I am really at my wits' end over this - I cannot believe it is so hard to delete images from a device. Any ideas how to go about this?