# Why can't I delete certain photos off of my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, ios

I cannot delete things off of my photos app on my iPhone. When I select any pictures there is no trash bin displayed to actually delete them. How can I proceed with deleting photos on the phone?

Comment: As written, your question gives us nothing to go on. What happens when you try to delete them? Is there any pattern you can find with which photos you can and can't delete? Have you done any troubleshooting at all?

Comment: We still have little to go on. What iPhone/iOS, what computer/OS/version of iTunes...? Have you tried a different cable? Lots of things you could tell us... we're here to help with your Apple device issues - your frustration is all your own.

Comment: Your question was still a bit unclear, I've edited it to the best of my understanding. If I got it wrong, please fix whatever is necessary. Also, could you please add a screenshot of your phone showing the screen where you select photos but don't see a trash bin?

Comment: It seems like you just removed the details i had added and changed nothing else.. anyway, idk how to add screenshots, and if you need screenshots to know what I'm talking about I doubt you know more than I know. There's a reason this was my last resort

Comment: Being rude or offensive towards the people trying to assist you in resolving your issue will not help nor contribute to resolving said issue. Kindly add to or edit your question to add more details allow the community to assist you. To take screenshots on your phone, press lock and home simultaneously; to add them to your question press the button that looks similar to a camera and select a photo from your photo library.

Comment: I removed the parts about your iTunes version, the sync issues and the problems in connecting the phone to your computer because they seem not relevant to the problem of deleting pictures on the phone. If these things *are* important (and they very well can be, we currently have to guess a bit here), please edit them back in. Besides screenshots it might also help to give us a step-by-step description of what you are doing and where things start to go wrong then.

Comment: The reason for screenshots is rather simple: On my screen there is a trash. So if you don't see one on yours, we are either looking at different screens or something is wrong with your Photos app. Either way, having a screenshot helps in nailing this down.

Comment: May be related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194812/how-can-i-delete-photos-from-the-photo-library-in-ios-8, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61593/how-to-delete-synced-photos-from-iphone-without-connecting-to-mac

Answer (score 1):

To delete pictures within the iOS Photos app, open Photos, tap on the text at top right

[image]

then select the photos you want to delete (so they get a blue checkmark) and tap on the Trash icon at bottom right.

[image]

PS: If this is not what you are seeing on your phone, please add more details to the question.